# Is the HTC One known by another name?

Tags: htc-one

Have just taken delivery of the new HTC One (15th March 2013) and am struggling to find relevant Internet search results.They all come back with info about HTC One X, HTC One V, HTC One S, XL, XT.. you get the idea. 
So, is there another name/word which might narrow down the field when looking for HTC One specific info ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've noticed that the HTC One is sometimes referred to as M7. Also, adding '2013' to a search improves the results, eg:
HTC One 2013 M7

Answer (score 2):

"One" is a line of phones and also a phone itself, much like Samsung and their Galaxy line.

There is a phone called just the "[HTC One](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_one-5313.php)" (Which I believe is the newest HTC phone), but there also [14 other devices](http://www.gsmarena.com/results.php3?sQuickSearch=yes&sName=HTC%20One) under the "One" name and are differentiated with 1 or 2 letters after the name.

Comment: Ok thanks. Seems like they haven't really thought about how people searching for the 'new' HTC One will find it, with so many 'old' HTC One's around. I was hoping there was another way to differentiate this latest one...

Comment: @sergeantKK - Yeah, HTC is doing things kinda backwards.  Samsung started with the Galaxy (it was an Android 1.5 device and their first Android device AFAICT) and then started adding on numbers, letters, and words, whereas HTC started with a bowl of alphabet soup and then used nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I search for info I type "HTC One 2013". That narrows things down a little.

Answer (score 0):

I knew that HTC One is called also HTC One M7.

Sources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_One,

http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=2215

http://leadergeeks.com/2013/02/19/code-name-m7-the-htc-one-is-finally-unveiled/

Answer (score 0):

HTC One is the latest phone released from HTC in their "One" series.

They named it "One" for its simplicity, which confuses a lot of people, when they look it up, and compare it to other devices from the series such as One X, One S, etc.

You can always look this phone up by it's codename which is M7.
For full codename list, you can check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTC_devices)